# How to search a text file based on columns using Bash Script

Tags: bash, unix, awk, grep, multiple-columns

I am creating a bash script contact list system and this is how it prints out.

```
=================
Menu
=================

Enter 1 for Insert new contact
Enter 2 for Print current contact list
Enter 3 for Search contact list
Enter 4 for Exit

Enter your selection:
```

When 2 is selected, basically it prints out the following:

```
Name                      Email                     Phone                    

Test                      test@aol.com              102-123-1234             
Data                      data@yahoo.com            345-345-5555             
Sally                     sally@yahoo.com           344-555-4930
```

To display this I use

```
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN{printf "%-12s %-15s %-12s\n","Name"," Email"," Phone"} {printf "%-12s %-15s %-12s\n",$1,$2,$3}' contacts.txt
```

I am having trouble with the option number 3 (searching contact list).

It prompts for:

```
Enter in data that you would like to search for: aol
```

Then the code behind is:

```
echo -e "Enter in data that you would like to search for: \c"
    read search
    grep "$search" contacts.txt
```

It prints out:

```
Test,test@aol.com,102-123-1234
```

This is because the text file `contacts.txt` stores the data in a comma separated list.

I want the search results to display in the columns like option number 2.  So when "aol" is the search it should print out:

```
Name                      Email                     Phone                    

Test                      test@aol.com              102-123-1234
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

use read and IFS, eg:

```
echo -e "Enter in data that you would like to search for: \c"
read search
printf "%16s%16s%16s\n\n" Name Email Phone
grep "$search" contacts.txt | while IFS="," read name email phone etc ; do 
  printf "%16s%16s%16s\n" "$name" "$email" "$phone"
done
```

Comment: note: you may use **printf "%-16s%-16s%-16s\n" ...** to align left instead of aligning text to the right.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v pattern=$search '/Name/{print $0} $0~pattern{print $0}' input
```

will output:

```
Name                      Email                     Phone                    
Test                      test@aol.com              102-123-1234
```

what does it?

- `-v` option creates a awk variable `pattern` assigns it with `$search`
- `/Name/` selects the title line
- `$0~pattern` matches the search patters

A much simpler version would be

```
awk -v pattern=$search '/Name/; $0~pattern' input
```

since `print $0` is the default action.

Comment: Have you tried it? This is not the way to compare a variable in a line. Try comparing these: `seq 10 | awk -v pat="3" '/pat/'` and `seq 10 | awk -v pat="3" '$0 ~ pat'`

Comment: @fedorqui my mistake. will corect the answer. Thank you

Comment: OK. Note, though, that the output won't be the way you indicate. It looks like this in the question because the OP is using `printf` with some formatting options. See my answer.